# Coveralls test percentage reduced by _typeof function

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, rollupjs, coveralls

I've got an NPM package that uses Coveralls. My percentage is at 85% and I can see that the last 15% has to do with the following func:

```
function _typeof(obj) {
  if (typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol") {
    _typeof = function (obj) {
      return typeof obj;
    };
  } else {
    _typeof = function (obj) {
      return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj;
    };
  }

  return _typeof(obj);
}
```

I assume this func is generated by Rollup because it is not in my src file.

Do I have to write tests for 'generated' code I haven't written my self? or is there some way to ignore this func.

Test command: `istanbul cover ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --report lcovonly -- -R spec && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js && rm -rf ./coverage`

Comment: I have a project that I forked off JSON5 on Github. That project uses Rollup, and reaches 100% coverage with Coveralls, and I'm pretty sure it's not basing that coverage on any of the Rollup-generated code. Maybe looking at the way that project is set up will help? https://github.com/json5/json5

Comment: What command are you using for code coverage?

Comment: I've added the command above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose the following.

- You could remove the final part that deletes the directory for the `./coverage`
- Look if the function `_typeof` appears in there and which is actually the path.
- Ignore the file with the `-x` argument when executing the `istanbul` task

If that doesn't work (You aren't able to locate the `_typeof` function by looking at the coverage report) you could try the following:

- Update to a newer version of rollup (maybe it's an issue that was fixed already)
- Change the babel config as they propose [here](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#babel) to distinguish between build and test runs
- Share a link to the project so people can look more closely to what the issue is, and which file is the targeted one.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the issue is that I'm running tests against my code after it has been transpiled, not before.